# Why does the country with no data always go on top?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I have a GeoJSON map and I am trying to hook it up in Highmaps. This map consists of 4 small squares (`"properties": {"name":"shape1"}`) that will have data and 1 big square that will never have data (`"properties": {"name":"base"}`) The purpose of this big square is to be a background shape for the others.

The problem is that the big shape will always be on top of the small ones. I have tried both of these arrangements in the GeoJSON file:

- placing the big shape **before** the small ones
- placing the big shape **after** the small ones

Please see **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/91ut26vz/)**

Is there any way to make the shapes with data stay on top of the ones with no data?

Comment: Simply for that base element set null value, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/91ut26vz/1/ - note it need to be first element in data array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply for that base element set null value, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/91ut26vz/1 - note it need to be first element in data array.

```
// Prepare random data
var data = [
    {
        "name": "base",
        "value": null
    },{
        "name": "shape1",
        "value": 728
    },
    {
        "name": "shape2",
        "value": 710
    },
    {
        "name": "shape3",
        "value": 963
    },
    {
        "name": "shape4",
        "value": 541
    }
];
```